# Different content for each vendor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a site that displays forms for different vendors.

Each vendor have some common properties, but there are some properties specific to some vendors. For instance one vendor asks for `customer's Title` (ie `Mr`, `Mrs`...) while others don't.
Even more, some of the properties may have different behavior. In the `Title` example above, one vendor could have it as a free text, while another would have it as an option select.

For this, i have a base class as a model, that holds the most common properties, and for each vendor i will create classes inheriting from the base to add the vendor specific properties, or change their behavior (like adding Data Annotations).

So, i would like to create forms specific to each vendor. What i have done and it really works, is create the generic one in the standard `Views`, `Models`, `Controllers` folders and each Vendor will have his own `Area`.

Is this really the right approach? I have seen that areas are mostly for mini sites or for localization.

Any opinion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your using the wrong tool for the job here (i.e. Areas), however, you aren't far off.

Instead of using a separate area, all you need to do here is introduce separate *views* per "vendor" type. You could create a base view and have each specific view inherit from that. In fact, you could probably get away with a single view e.g.

```
public class VendorViewModel
{
    ...
    public CustomerViewModel Customer { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> TitleOptions { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Given the above model, your view could look like

```
@model VendorViewModel

...
@if (Model.Customer != null)
{
    // make title selection configurable
    @if (Model.Customer.TitleOptions != null)
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customer.Title, new SelectList(m.Customer.TitleOptions, "[Select title]"))
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Customer.Title)   
    }
    ...
}
```

This effectively builds your view based on a particular vendors requirements e.g.

- Leave the `Customer` property `null` if you don't need to capture customer info
- Leave the `TitleOptions` property `null` if you want to have free-form text entry for title

This is just a simple example of how you can build up your view dynamically, and all in a single view. You could tidy it up a little by moving the customer view stuff into it's own partial view and only rendering that if required e.g.

```
@if (Model.Customer != null)
{
    @Html.RenderPartial("CustomerView", Model.Customer)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I was expecting an answer like this. Can you provide some guidance on the View inheritance? Also, do you think what i do in the with the model (apart from having them in a different area) is ok?

Comment: @jyparask I have edited my answer to give you an example of how you can achieve the *dynamic* form building you are after. Yes, inheritance is fine for your scenario.